# Single SIgn-On IIS Site intermittently responding with 401 errors some mornings on one of two sites

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, credentials, http-status-code-401, intermittent

Currently in our testing environment, **one** IIS site (out of two) intermittently logs 401 authentication errors. This is picked up by monitoring through the following log extract: (shortened)

GET / - 80 -  Microsoft+Monitoring+Agent+7.1.10184.0 - 401 2 5 0

When attempting to log into this site during this period, credentials are requested, even though the site is configured for **SSO**. If this prompt is cancelled (which I assume occurs since credentials are not expected) the 401 - Unauthorized is provided.

Interestingly enough, this issue occurs intermittently - occurred 2 days out of 7 this week.

We currently have a workaround of restarting only the affected site, which then allows users to access via SSO, and we even have an automated task for this.

However I would still like to resolve the root issues itself.
Even gaining a greater understanding how a user SSO request can be transformed into needing credentials, and what common causes to this may be.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit - iis version is 6.2
Windows server 2012 R2 is also used

Comment: There are tons of SSO solutions out there, so if you don't edit the question to include more details, nothing can be discussed further.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Added versions, will also open a case through Microsoft support